# Remove single quote and double quote + white spaces from string rails 2 ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, gsub

I have functionality to upload image and in that image if image name have any single quotes or double quotes or white space then I got error to uploaded at amazon

So how to remove wild characters and spaces from image name?

**Sorry one edit**
I need to add %20 in place of white space

Please help me.

Comment: I have tried .gsub(' ', '%20') for white spaces

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
string.gsub(/\s|"|'/, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
string.tr(" '\"", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use gsub multiple times :

```
string.gsub(/"|'/, '').gsub(/\s/, '%20')
```

or use gsub! to change the original string like -

```
string.gsub!(/"|'/, '').gsub!(/\s/, '%20')
```